# downloading a file from a server and saving it in a specific location without user intraction

Tags: apache-flex

I want to download a file from the server and save it in a particular location of the disk without user interaction. All this I want to do it in Flex. If anyone has a solution please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. You cannot download a file and save it into user's machine without user's knowledge and permission. If that was possible, that would be a big security issue; I can overwrite any file on your machine while you enjoy the fancy animation on my home page - how does that sound?

If it is a small piece of data you can store it as a [shared object](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) aka Flash cookies

> The `SharedObject` class is used to read and store limited amounts of data on a user's computer or on a server. Shared objects offer real-time data sharing between multiple client SWF files and objects that are persistent on the local computer or remote server. Local shared objects are similar to browser cookies and remote shared objects are similar to real-time data transfer devices. To use remote shared objects, you need Adobe Flash Media Server.